# Как добавить действие при нажатии на textview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone

У меня есть `textview` и мне надо, чтобы совершалось действие, когда на него нажимаешь.

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: что за действие то хоть?

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо объявить, что Ваш `UIViewController` использует `UITextViewDelegate`, а также добавить property `IBOutlet` на Ваш `textview`.

Для этого в добавьте его название в `<...>`, например:

```
@interface MyViewConroller : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;
```

Затем Вам необходимо добавить следующее, например, в метод `-viewDidLoad()` у вашего `MyViewController`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myTextView.delegate = self;
}
```

Теперь всё готово, Вам осталось реализовать метод делегата, который позволит "отловить" событие, когда пользователь нажал на `myTextView`. Этот метод называется `- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView;`. В него Вам и необходимо добавить нужные действия, например:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if ([textView isEqual:self.myTextView]) //гарантия того, что пользователь нажал именно на необходимый textView
    {
        //ваши действия, которые Вы хотите реализовать
    }
}
```

Comment: Здесь нет пояснений **почему** это работает именно так, я привел конкретный пример **как это реализовать**. Если есть необходимость пояснить что-то — напишите об этом в комментариях.

Comment: Почему оригинальный вопрос 6-ю людьми (на данный момент) отмечен как "неточный", а также, якобы, надо уточнить подробности вопроса, а в комментариях спрашивают какое действие хочет реализовать автор? Вопрос автором поставлен чёткий: как запрограммировать действие при нажатии юзером на textView, как разница какое действие? Ответ — использовать метод из делагата для UITextView. Автор задал очень точечный вопрос и правок он не требует. Ответ на вопрос представлен в моём посте, который, как я могу судить, верен и корректен. Я не пытаюсь кого-то задеть, просто странно видеть такое комьюнити.